# How to display non distinct or duplicate records in cosmosdb sql?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a cosmosdb collection that has records like(I have shown 2 records for sample):

```
[
{
    "id": "0000001|0000000|0000002",
    "primarycode": "0000001",
    "code2": "0000000",
    "code3": "0000002",
    "array": [
        {
            "requiredvalue": "79050040002010",
            "someobject": {
                "abc": "02",
                "def": "05",
                "ghi": "04",
                "jkl": "03"
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "0000001|0000003|0000002",
    "primarycode": "0000001",
    "code2": "0000003",
    "code3": "0000002",
    "array": [
        {
            "requiredvalue": "79050040002010",
            "someobject": {
                "abc": "02",
                "def": "05",
                "ghi": "04",
                "jkl": "03"
            }
        },
        {
            "requiredvalue": "79050040005680",
            "someobject": {
                "abc": "02",
                "def": "05",
                "ghi": "04",
                "jkl": "03"
            }
        }
    ]
}
]
```

What i need to get here is the common "requiredvalue" from both these records(which is "79050040002010"), and the condition is these records have the same "primaryCode" but the "code2" is different, hence the id is also different.

I am able to get the distinct "requiredvalue" from these records with the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.requiredvalue FROM c JOIN f IN c.array WHERE c.primarycode="0000001"
```

This would return the "requiredvalue" with "79050040002010", "79050040005680".
But i just want the common "requiredvalue" which is "79050040002010".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `GROUP BY` clause that hasn't been introduced too long ago. Example:

```
SELECT s.requiredvalue
FROM (
    SELECT f.requiredvalue, COUNT(1) AS count
    FROM c
    JOIN f IN c.array1
    WHERE c.primarycode='0000001'
    GROUP BY f.requiredvalue
) s
WHERE s.count > 1
```

edit: hereby also a query to get the overlapping requiredvalue for every primarycode

```
SELECT s.primarycode, s.requiredvalue
FROM (
    SELECT c.primarycode, f.requiredvalue, COUNT(1) AS count
    FROM c
    JOIN f IN c.array1
    GROUP BY c.primarycode, f.requiredvalue
) s
WHERE s.count > 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked perfectly. I think you typed array1 as a typo it should be array only, I am sure you know this. Thanks once again! :)

Comment: And what do you think should be done if i want to get these common required value for each and every different primarycode in the collection. Like primarycode with value 000 has 2 records(each record has 2-2 requiredvalue) and within them 1 common requiredvalue, similarly 4 other records are there of primarycode 111(each record has 2-2 requiredvalue) and within them 3 are common requiredvalue. I would want to display the common requiredvalue corresponding to each primarycode. If you could drive me to the correct direction that would be great.

Comment: @RitikPatel Not entirely sure what you the expected output is you want, but see the code in the edit above

Comment: you are correct with this code, I tried this one but the output format here is:
`
[
    {
        "primarycode": "0001",
        "requiredvalue": "90159902053710"
    },
    {
        "primarycode": "0001",
        "requiredvalue": "90159902054120"
    }
]
`
But the result format i wish to get is:
`
[
    {
        "primarycode": "0001",
        "requiredvalue": [
                     "90159902053710",
                     "90159902054120"
        ]
    }
]
So to have all the required values in 1 array. Is that possible?I have been trying to do this but cant find a way.

Comment: @RitikPatel I don't think it's possible to group into an array as the array methods are not aggregate functions. At least I would not know how to do it

Comment: Yeah you are correct there isn’t a way to do this. Do you suggest any other way in which i can show all the different overlapping requiredvalues associated with primarycodes more closely.

Comment: Hi! I am getting varying number of results 20-30 records up down after i rerun the query each time. What might be the reason for it?

Comment: @RitikPatel Hard to say. I suggest you make a new question about that as a query definately shouldn't return such results unless underlying data is changed. Maybe you are using the API wrong (e.g. not using the continuation token)

Comment: How would you create a query to find duplicate items and show their unique id? You can only group on properties that are the same and this show how many there are but you cannot take and item’s unique id property into a Group statement.